# Passage in the proof on fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have that

$\alpha x_1^{h_1}x_2^{h_2} \cdot \cdots x_n^{h_n}$

is the leading term of $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{K}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$. Now define the symmetric polynomials in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$

$g = \alpha \sigma_1^{h_1-h_2}\sigma_2^{h_2-h_3} \cdot \cdots \sigma_{n-1}^{h_{n-1} - h_n} \sigma_{n}^{h_n}$

I understand that $f$ and $g$ have the same leading term, (it is proven by expanding $g$). But I don't understand this part ''Hence $f_1 = f — g$ has a strictly smaller leading term according to the lexicographic ordering.''

How can see this if I know only the leading term of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $f$ and $g$ have the same leading term and this term is largest according to the lex ordering with $x_1>x_2>\ldots>x_n$.

Now in $f_1=f-g$ the leading terms of $f$ and $g$ cancel and so the leading term of $f_1$ is  smaller than that of $f,g$. It is one term of $f$ or $g$ but not the leading term of $f$ and $g$.